# Can't decode cyrillic value from Request.QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, webforms

On my IIS7 I have ASP.NET WebForms site, and I use cyrillic values in the query string. I use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` for params when do redirect, in the end I have url like:

```
http://mysite.com/Search.aspx?SearchText=текст
```

When I try to read param `SearchText` value (include `HttpUtility.Decode()` function) it returns me a wrong value of `ÑÐµÐºÑÑ`, but should return `текст`

It works on localhost on ASP.NET developer server, but doesn't on IIS7 (include local IIS7)
In my web.config I set up line

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

but it still doesn't work.

Appreciate any help,

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `redirect` function, yes inside it there is this call

`url = UrlEncodeRedirect(url);`

thats break the Cyrilic, Greece characters and probably others. If I remember well, (I say remember because this issue is from my experience some months ago) the break to the characters is after the `?` symbol. In any case I have the same issue.

Possible solutions:

- Make your custom redirect, maybe not so good as the original, but you can by pass this issue.
- Find some alternative way to your redirect logic.
- Make your custom text encode that use only valid url characters that are not change by the redirect, and then decodes them again back. The minous on that is that will be like hidden text and not visible readable search word.

This is the very basic of the redirect.

```
public static void RedirectSimple(string url, bool endResponse)
{
    HttpResponse MyResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    MyResponse.Clear();
    MyResponse.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    MyResponse.StatusCode = 302;
    MyResponse.Status = "302 Temporarily Moved";
    MyResponse.RedirectLocation = url;

    MyResponse.Write("<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>\r\n");
    MyResponse.Write("<h2>Object moved to <a href=\"" + url + "\">here</a>.</h2>\r\n");
    MyResponse.Write("</body></html>\r\n");

    if (endResponse){
        MyResponse.End();
    }
}
```

You can make it a function and try it to see if works correctly.

Comment: This is from experience, I have the same issue, analyze it and search it so deep and found that. Of course I may have done some mistake and there is alternative solution - but for the moment I have re-write my one redirect base on asp.net redirect.

Comment: Hm, very strange why this works on local ASP.NET development server, also forget to say that it worked successfully on IIS6 (windows 2003 server)

Comment: @ihorko I do not have answers for all - I use IIS7, and local IIS5 for tests, and I used to have the same issues with redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Problem actually was in UrlRewriting.net that I use in my web-application.

Comment: then select yours as answer, and I will delete my.

Comment: I have a similar problem, with a different application. Can you help?
I'm seeing %u00d1%u0081%u00d1%u008b%u00d1%u0080%u00d1%u008c%u00d0%u00b5%u00d0%u00b2%u00d1%u008b%u00d0%u00b5-%u00d1%u0082%u00d0%u00be%u00d0%u00b2jjj%u00d0%u00b0%u00d1%u0080%u00d1%u008b in the querystring, and it's decoded to ÑÑÑÑÐµÐ²ÑÐµ-ÑÐ¾Ð²jjjÐ°ÑÑ

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem by converting the value to ToBase64String:

1. Before redirecting to a target page I encoded the value:

   ```
       Dim Data() As Byte  'For the data to  be encoded

       'Convert the string into a byte array
       Dim encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
       Data = encoding.GetBytes(ParamToPass)

       'Converting to ToBase64String
       Dim EncodedStringToPass as string = Convert.ToBase64String(Data)

       Page.Response.Redirect("TargetPage.aspx?Param=" & EncodedStringToPass, False)
   ```
2. At the target page:

   ```
       Dim Data() As Byte  'For the data to  be decoded
       Data = Convert.FromBase64String(Page.Request.Params("Param"))

       Dim encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
       Dim ParamToPass As String = encoding.GetString(Data)
   ```

P.S. The only disadvantage of the method is that one cannot see the real value of the parameters in url string of browsers. But in my case this made no problem